# Equalizer to cut specific frequencies on microphone input

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, equalizer

Does ubuntu have a utility which can adjust levels for specific INPUT sound frequencies?

We are doing video conferencing and one of our co-workers has a lot of unavoidable ambient noise. He would like to isolate particular frequencies coming from his microphone and cut them before they are passed to the video conferencing software.

I checked out pulseaudio equalizer, but it seems to be limited to sound OUTPUT, not INPUT.

Comment: Unfortunately all the relevant [PulseAudio filter modules](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index10h2) only apply to sinks, while microphones are sources.

Comment: does your conferencing software support the JACK audio connection kit ?

Answer (score 0):

PulseAudio Equalizer and PulseAudio Volume Control are two different pieces of software. PulseAudio Volume Control will allow you to adjust input volumes so is probably what you are looking for. In a terminal type

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

If that is not what you are looking for or is too basic, you could try JAMin, which is an Audio Mastering interface designed for input channels. It looks very in depth.

http://jamin.sourceforge.net/en/about.html

Comment: the OP is looking for an equalizer, not a volume control

Comment: Sorry, I misread the original question. I've edited my answer to give details of an input equalizer

Comment: Nice :-) , but it will require the installation of JACK, hook it up to pulseaudio both sources and sinks to send from PA to JACK and return from JACK to PA....that is some serious audio plumbing, not for the faint hearted ;-)